# data-wow-duration vs animation-duration?

Tags: animate.css, wow.js

This post is in relation to animate.css and wow.js. This might be a very silly question but what is the difference between animation-duration and animation-delay vs data-wow-duration and data-wow-delay?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

data-wow-duration is the length of time the animation will play - and - data-wow-delay is how long to wait before playing the animation.

Steve